# Specific setup of a lab : Two VMs with internet and no host communication

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I would like to setup a lab for couple tests.

I have two VMs on VirtualBox. I need to let :

- VM1 and VM2 can connect to internet.
- VM1 ↔ VM2  can communicate with each other.
- VM2 has automatic assignment of IP from a DHCP server is enabled.
- I need no communication btw VM2 and the Host.

Please, I am kind of locked. Do I need to setup :

- VM1 and VM2 with two adapters for NAT Network or single adapter with a bridged mode ?

Comment: Default NAT from the host machine allows: 1 VM1 and VM2 to connect to Internet; 2 VM1 and VM2 to communicate with each other; VM1 and VM2 will get automatic DHCP from the Host machine. Your VM adapters are from the host. You should not need two VM network adapters, but the second one, if you want it, would come from a USB NIC and then pass through USB from Host to Guest

Comment: alright very genius :) I 'm working on this ...